# Can Videogame physiotherapy help with dorsal hand pain?

Tags: pain, hand, physiotherapy, dorsal-upper-back-side

I am thinking how to alleviate irregular bilateral dorsal hand pain. 
The origin can be C7/C8 dermatomes or radial/ulnar nerve. 
Etiology can be excessive sitting on camping chair (some hours daily) and/or excessive typing with computers (hours daily), respectively.

I am thinking videogame console *Nintendo Switch* as physiotherapy for the former etiology agent. The latter one can be removed by just sitting better.